# How to build an AJAX API that is not cross domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, cross-domain

I'm building an AJAX API, and I've been getting the 405 error (presumably because I'm trying to make a cross domain request.

```
var API = function() {


    API.AddToCart = function(item_id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/add-cart-item/" + item_id,
            success: function(){
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I don't understand what makes this cross-domain, and how to not make a cross-domain request. Can somebody help explain this concept to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your server does not support POST method for that endpoint. Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405 for more explanations.

Comment: Amazing, I have no idea how you figured that out. I was trying to do something weird by pulling data out of an URL in a 'GET' request. I don't really understand AJAX is capable of sending data to an URL. You may have noticed I don't have a 'data:*' section in my AJAX request. Do you know of a link or website that explains that concept?

Comment: If you want to learn more and understand core concepts of AJAX check out this link [AJAX - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Answer (score 1):

Just because you get a 405 doesn't necessarily mean that you have a CORS problem. Are you sure that POST methods are allowed for that method on the server side?

Comment: @JacobHenning Sometimes it's a CORS issue but, if you're not posting cross-domain it's usually because the method only allows certain types of requests, GET and not POST, for example. By decorating your controller methods with [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] attributes, you're specifically allowing only those types of requests. You can also combine them [HttpGet, HttpPost] if you want to restrict PUT or DELETE or other types of requests